# Accidently unsubscribed e-mail for stackoverflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, email-notification

I am trying to resubscribe to e-mail notifications from stackoverflow, since I accedently clicked on the e-mail to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317589/rick) and in there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Didn't see the prefs tab.